# how to pass from numpy matrix to numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scikit-learn

I am new to Python and Numpy so maybe the title of my question is wrong.

I load some data from a matlab file

```
data=scipy.io.loadmat("data.mat")
x=data['x']
y=data['y']
>>> x.shape
(2194, 12276)
>>> y.shape
(2194, 1)
```

`y` is a vector and I would like to have `y.shape = (2194,)`.

I do not the difference between `(2194,)` and `(2194,1)` but seems that sklearn.linear_model.LassoCV encounter an error if you try to load `y` such that `y.shape=(2194,1)`.

So how  can I change my `y` vector in order to have `y.shape=(2194,)`??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First convert to an array, then squeeze to remove extra dimensions:

```
y = y.A.squeeze()
```

In steps:

```
In [217]: y = np.matrix([1,2,3]).T

In [218]: y
Out[218]: 
matrix([[1],
        [2],
        [3]])

In [219]: y.shape
Out[219]: (3, 1)

In [220]: y = y.A

In [221]: y
Out[221]: 
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3]])

In [222]: y.shape
Out[222]: (3, 1)

In [223]: y.squeeze()
Out[223]: array([1, 2, 3])

In [224]: y = y.squeeze()

In [225]: y.shape
Out[225]: (3,)
```

Comment: I like the `y.A` syntax (which I believe is an alias for `y.__array__()`) to get the underlying array better than `np.asarray`.

Comment: ok it works thank! But can you add a little explanation about the difference between elements with size (2194,) and (2194,1) ?

Comment: The data is the same, but the `shape` is different; so is the number of dimensions (`ndim`).  Get into a Python shell, import numpy, and play around with a small array. Look at is shape and ndim, transpose it, squeeze it, convert it to matrix and back.  Add dimensions.  In matlab arrays have a minimum of 2 dimensions.  numpy matrix is modeled on old matlab arrays which couldn't have more dimensions.

Comment: @Donbeo, As @hpaulj says, they'r the same data, just different views.  As you become more familiar with numpy, the concept of a [`view` vs a `copy`](http://wiki.scipy.org/Tentative_NumPy_Tutorial#head-1529ae93dd5d431ffe3a1001a4ab1a394e70a5f2) will become important. Certain actions jut give a view, for example, `reshape` and slicing (`a[:10]` is a view of the first ten items), and `np.asarray` doesn't copy the data if possible.  Others make a copy, for example, `np.array` and 'fancy indexing' `a[a>5]` both return copies.